# is it possible to install copy protection in a telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, copy-protection, node-telegram-bot-api

is it possible to install copy protection in a telegram bot?
the bot sends docx files, images and text.
I would like to make it so that they cannot be copied but can be viewed. I couldn't find anything in the telegram bot api documentation, I can't Google it either.
the bot is written in `node.js`. used the `node-telegram-bot-api` library
For the third day I have been struggling with the question, suddenly who knows if it is possible at all. Maybe it can be done in some other way. For example, to raise a web server where you can watch content and send only links in the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can de-activate buttons like "Save As..." or "Share to..." by adding a `protect_content` parameter. It is available for many methods, including [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), [sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), [sendDocument](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument).

Of course anything that can be viewed can also be copied in some way or another. Nonetheless it provides some protection.